# CMake, in add_test, how do you specify different categories

Tags: cmake

I have projects with unit, fuzz, and integration tests. I only want unit tests failing customer builds. I use fuzz and integration for CI. What I’d love to have is generated targets such as:

```
make test
make fuzz
make integration
```

I’ve been scouring the cmake source code all morning and haven’t found a way to generate something other than:

```
make test
```

I have to be missing something obvious. Any ideas?

Comment: A combination of [names for the tests](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_test.html) and [`LABELS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/LABELS.html) should make it possible to do what you want. You can make it so you write `ctest -L unit` to run unit tests, `ctest -L fuzz` to run fuzz tests, etc (see [ctest(1)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html#options))

Comment: @justin do you know a way for it to generate the targets, For some build systems like visual studio Id love to just have the correct projects generated.

Comment: I don’t really want make install running the integration tests (a lot of build containers are sandboxed)

Comment: If you use [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html), you should be able to make a custom test runner to run just what you need, then use `add_test` with that custom target (something like `${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target custom_test_runner` as the command)

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can add a new configuration type (in addition to the default `Debug`, `Release`, `RelWithDebInfo`, `MinSizeRel`) and then qualify the test with that configuration type.
So for example:

```
set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES
        Debug                   
        DebugFuzzer               
        Release                 
        RelWithDebInfo          
        MinSizeRel)

# ...

add_test(NAME FuzzTest COMMAND FuzzTestDriver CONFIGURATIONS DebugFuzzer)
```

This will let you run the fuzz tests only when you build with `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DebugFuzzer`

Comment: Nice! I’ll give it a try